# Add function to timer

Tags: ios, swift, function, timer, xcode6

If I want to add a function as fast as the timer hits 0. 
Do anyone have any tips? Here is the Code that I want to implement it in.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var Counterlabel: UILabel!
    var Nbr = 51
    var timerValue = 52
    var timer = NSTimer()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("Counter"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    @IBAction func Btn1(sender: AnyObject) {
        Nbr = timerValue - 1
        timerValue = timerValue - 1;
    }

    func Counter(){
        Nbr -= 1
        Counterlabel.text = "\(Nbr)"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call a function with delay according to your timer like this,

```
func delay(delay:Double, closure:()->()) {
     dispatch_after(
          dispatch_time(
               DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,
               Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))
          ),
     dispatch_get_main_queue(), closure)
}

delay(Double(self.Nbr)) {
    //Do your work here
}
```

the above function is referenced from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24034544/dispatch-after-gcd-in-swift)

Comment: Thank you so much, Really appreciate it:)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   var countDown = 0 

    func Counter()
  {
     countDown--;
     if countDown == 0 
    {
       // reset the timer     
    }
  }
```